# Splice only working part of the time

Tags: javascript, splice

Here i have an array with undefined number of elements. I tried to print random element of this array and cut it. Here my code.

```
function rand(min, max){
   return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min).toFixed(0);
}
$('#do').click(function(){
    var count = chamarr.length;
    var num = 0;
    if (count == 1) {
      $('#output').html('Nothing can found');
    } else {
      num = rand(1,chamarr.length);
      $('#output').html(chamarr[num]);
      chamarr.splice(num,1);
    }
 });
```

When I logged an array is cutted, I saw that always ok, but sometimes element is not cut!

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I have no clue what your last sentence means. Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: (Not that it's stopped me from writing a guess as an answer, of course. JavaScript developers, please check my answer carefully, as it assumes that JS works vaguely like the languages I'm used to :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My *guess* is that the problem is with your `randnum` method:

```
function rand(min, max){
   return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min).toFixed(0);
}
```

I *believe* this will give you a value in the range `[min, max]` - inclusive at *both ends*. (Well, actually, it will give you a string version of that value as `toFixed` returns a string, but when you use it later it'll get coerced back into a number.)

Now you're calling it like this:

```
num = rand(1,chamarr.length);
```

So if the array is 6 elements long, you'll get a value in the range `[1, 6]`. But then you'll try to take `chamarr[num]` - and the range of valid indexes is `[0, 5]` as arrays are 0-based. If you try to take element 6, that will give you `undefined` - but then *splicing* at element 6 won't do anything.

I would change your `rand` method to be *exclusive* at the upper bound, like this:

```
function rand(min, max) {
   return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min).toFixed(0);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
num = rand(0, chamarr.length);
```

That will give you a value in the right range for both indexing and splicing.

EDIT: In response to comments etc:

- It's probably worth removing the `toFixed(0)` part of the `rand` function; you don't *really* want a string, after all. This isn't really part of what was wrong before, but it's generally cleaner:

  ```
  function rand(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
  ```
- You might also want a version of the function that makes the `0` lower bound implicit
- If you're not going to use random numbers anywhere else in your code you *could* inline the `Math.floor()` / `Math.random()` calls instead of having a separate function, but personally I'd want to keep them well away from the "logic" code which just wants to get a random number and use it.
- The reason I'd change the function is that having an exclusive upper bound is much more common in computer science - it typically goes along with 0-indexing for things like collections. You typically write `for` loops with inclusive lower bounds and exclusive lower bounds, etc.

Comment: +1, and that definitely explains the word 'sometimes' in the question. ) And `arr[arr.length]` will just evaluate to `undefined`, no error will be thrown.

Comment: You shouldn't change the function itself (it returns a string now) but how it's called. `(0, length-1)` or without the function at all `var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*chamarr.length)`

Comment: An out-of-bounds access will actually return `undefined`, not `null`, but the rest of your analysis is spot-on :)

Comment: @Esailija: Why not change both? Making the function use a range of `[min, max)` is more idiomatic in computer science, IMO. I have no problem with extracting a function for generating a random number in a range though... I wouldn't want to see the `Math.floor` etc calls *everywhere* I wanted an integer. It might be best to get rid of the `toFixed(0)` call though :)

Comment: @JonSkeet That might be true but the function is very likely supposed to be equal to http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php which works with `[min, max]` I didn't notice the `.toFixed()` was there to begin with, I thought it was your addition :D

Comment: @Esailija: Just because PHP diverges from the rest of the CS world doesn't mean it's a good idea to emulate that broken-ness :)

Comment: Heh, there is a full on project trying to emulate the broken-ness of php in javascript http://phpjs.org

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you always write answers with all these details for these simple questions? I'm impressed.

Comment: @MaxArt: When I have time, yes :) There's often more than the OP can learn from a situation than just how to get past their most immediate problem. Ideally, I like to address the biggest picture - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11323359/22656) for another recent example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `num` is an index out of range. You should do this:

```
num = rand(0, chamarr.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your logic:

```
function rand(max) {
  return Math.round( Math.random() * max ) % max;
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    len = arr.length,
    num = rand(len);

if ( len === 1 ) {
    // Do your "Nothing here" output
}
else {
    arr.splice(num, 1);
    // etc, etc, etc...
}
```